# What is this Vietnamese Food?

Tags: food-identification, vietnamese-cuisine

Several years ago, I had a friend of Vietnamese descent.  She went back to visit her home country and returned with gifts.  I was given a box (possibly yellow) containing several foil-wrapped cubes or rectangles.  They were a sort of caked or compressed powder, and somewhat unpleasant to eat.  I have since lost touch with my friend, but I would love to be able to track down (or at least identify) this food.

I remember that the first ingredient listed was "grease pig."

Comment: Could you say something about the flavour? What did it remind you of? Was it sweet, bitter, salty...?

Comment: It didn't have a distinct or memorable flavor, but I certainly didn't find it tasty.  Maybe kind of...meaty?

Comment: Could it have been like a bouillon cube?

Comment: Quite possibly.

Comment: I wonder if it was like a *pho* seasoning cube.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a stock cube to me: http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l3c5cjve3d1qzx5fuo1_500.jpg

Answer (score 5):

Does it look [like this](http://www.rockmanusa.com/image/cache/data/Reg.%20Images/SOUP-BO-650x650.jpg)?  I have some in my pantry now.  (Don't tell anyone.)

By request, the box contents: inside a cellophane sleeve, 4 foil-wrapped cubes.  Here's one:[image: Pho cube]

Texture is very much like a boullion cube - hard, with a bit of sticky give when pushed.  Salty, as expected, but also sweetish with a distinct flavor of caramelized onions and star anise.

Comment: No.  There was no recognizable French or English on the box (aside from the ingredient list).  Sorry!

Comment: If you could post a picture of the *contents* of that box, it might be exactly what the OP was thinking of, just a different brand.

Comment: @Jefromi: Excellent idea - done.

Comment: That's probably it! Is there an ingredient list?

Comment: @AdeleC: salt, sugar, MSG, and spices.

Answer (score 4):

Does it's look like this?

[image: mung bean cake 1]
or
[image: mung bean cake 2]

This cake is made from mung bean powder and it is bright yellow. Once upon a time, it was wrapped in plant leaves, but today, it is factory-produced and wrapped in foil.

The Mung bean cake, or `Bánh đậu xanh`, tastes very sweet. It is served with tea.

Comment: Davuz, welcome to Seasoned advice! I inserted the images you had linked, and used the occasion to rewrite your post with better grammar. We are a collaboratively edited site, and such editing is common here. I hope I could retain your original meaning. If not, you can revert the post to its earlier version, or edit my version further.

Comment: @rumtscho Thank you for edited! My English is not good!